# I'm trying to add the bookmark in word using VB.net..have anyone got idea?

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging

Public Class Add_bookmark

    Const fileName As String = "F:\vb\part2 here\AddRemove.docx"
    Const bookmarkName As String = "Page1"

    Private Sub Add_bookmark_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Using doc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, True)
            Dim docBody As Body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
            Dim addBookmark As BookmarkStart = docBody.Descendants(Of BookmarkStart)().FirstOrDefault(Function(a) a.Name = bookmarkName)
            If addBookmark Is Nothing Then
                Throw New Exception(String.Format("Bookmark {0} not found", bookmarkName))
            End If
            'addBookmark.InsertAt(bookmarkName)
            doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you experiencing a specific issue?

Comment: i cannot add the bookmark

Answer (score 0):

Here's my recommendation that I think will pretty much solve most Open XML SDK issue.  They have both a comparison tool and a code generation tool.  Use thoughts to your advantage.

1. Create the document you want to see in Microsoft Word.  Save It.
2. Open the document again, add a bookmark.  Save it again, but under a different name.
3. Open the XML SDK comparison tool and select both documents.  It'll show you the differences, and also will show you the sample .NET code that can be used to create the 2 documents.  In this case, you'll focus on the differences in the code.

Comment: i don't get it actually

Comment: have you used the tool before? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c74a60e6-a34b-47c6-a9a5-7993b0070d9f/compare-two-word-documents-c-and-get-differences?forum=oxmlsdk its installed with the sdk